# Entered EU on EU passport, marked as leaving EU when entering Gibraltar on Canadian passport. Will this cause problems?

Tags: schengen, legal, dual-nationality, passport-stamps, gibraltar

I have dual nationality, Canada-Poland (EU). Born and raised in Canada, but parents are Polish. Normally reside in Canada.

Background: back in November 2021, I flew to the UK via Toronto > London > Toronto for three days for a wedding, and used my Canadian passport.

So now in March 2022, I have been traveling around Europe for the last few weeks, having entered Europe on my Polish (EU) passport.

I was in Spain last week, and wanted to cross the border into Gibraltar (UK sovereign territory).

Because I was entering Gibraltar, i.e., UK sovereign territory, I thought it would be wise to use my Canadian passport again — since I had used it for the UK a few months ago.

I went to Gibraltar border control and handed the guy my Canadian passport. He scanned it, flipped through it…and stamped it. Which I thought was weird, since the UK never stamps, but I thought, “Ok, maybe it’s just a Gibraltar thing.”

Shortly after, I checked the passport and saw it was an exit stamp from **Spain**!

So now, I have an EU exit stamp on my Canadian passport, and literally nothing else. No entry stamp (obviously, since I entered Europe on my EU passport). Passport is quite new and blank except for this EU exit stamp, since I’ve only used it for Canada, America, and the UK.

I crossed back in Spain from Gibraltar on my Polish passport, no issue—they didn’t scan it or stamp it or check or anything, just waved me through.

However, I’m concerned that there is now a “record” of me leaving Spain as a Canadian, but no record of my entry as a Canadian. Also, that I am permanently overstaying in Gibraltar, since I entered on a Canadian passport, but never technically “left”.

Don’t know why the officer didn’t remark about lack of proof of entry to Spain on that Canadian passport, but who knows.

Anyway, I’m quite worried now about how things will play out.

Thoughts? Or am I overreacting?

Comment: Thanks for the swift and thorough reply. Regarding applying for visas though … I don’t want other countries to know I am a dual citizen, but I guess that is self-evident now from the single exit stamp 

Comment: Re: dual citizenship. A stray stamp might raise questions if someone studies your passport very carefully but oversights are not rare. Case in point: A border guard applying a Schengen exit stamp is always supposed to look for the corresponding entry stamp. Yet, what happened to you is that they didn't find it but stamped anyway.

Comment: Yeah I’m worried about the Gibraltar side of things, and the UK, and if I ever enter the UK on my Canadian passport again (which I usually do).

Comment: A brief comment, you should read up on your rights as an EU citizen in Poland and elsewhere in the EU. They are wide-ranging, from living and working to running for town council ...

Comment: Yes, I am more worried now about visas when applying for third countries (which I usually used my Canadian passport for, in the past)

Comment: On a side note, a sole exit stamp can also easily happen just by going to a country where you get stamps when talking to an officer and no stamps when you use the automated gate. Just enter through the automated gate and exit through a booth with an officer.

Comment: @AndreKR There is sometimes an officer sitting at a desk behind a row of gates, the theory is that you have to approach them to get stamped once you cleared the automated check. The reality of course is tha it's not happening and this is only one of many inconsistencies that make stamps unreliable.

Comment: @Relaxed If they wanted everyone to approach them they would surely post a sign? I'm pretty sure they are there only for when the gate flags you as not cleared.

Comment: @AndreKR There may be signs, the details depend on the specific country / checkpoint. But I can tell you border guards are not only there for people flagged by the gate, even if that's also part of their role. Importantly, it's not everyone who need to approach them: Most people going through these gates would be EU citizens who do not require stamps. In fact, not every country opens them to third-country citizens (US, Japan…) even if that does happen.

Answer (score 27):

None of this matters. You're a Polish citizen, you have a right to be in Spain more-or-less indefinitely (with some small caveats but nothing that matters in this scenario). Using your Canadian passport doesn't change that basic fact and, in the highly unlikely event that someone anywhere in the EU ever questions you about that stamp or any incomplete travel record, establishing your Polish citizenship will be enough to clear up the issue.

> I crossed back in Spain from Gibraltar on my Polish passport, no issue—they didn’t scan it or stamp it or check or anything, just waved me through.

That's pretty typical. Spanish border guards are aware of the rules I just mentioned. They are forbidden from stamping your Polish passport and have absolutely no reason to check anything else. They could scan it if they suspect it's fake or stolen or want to check if there is an alert for your arrest but other than that they would not deny you entry. In particular, previous stays or the purpose of your travel are completely irrelevant.

I am not so sure about the Gibraltar side of things. The UK relies on passenger manifests and data from transportation companies but with Gibraltar being accessible by road and still figuring out its relationship with Spain after Brexit, I am not up to date on exactly how they handle immigration.

Importantly, overstaying is a material fact. If you are out of the territory, you cannot be overstaying. What a stray stamp could potentially do is create some confusion or reverse the burden of proof but it doesn't mean you're overstaying anywhere. Again, I don't know about Gibraltar but EU law is explicit about that.

Generally speaking, oversights are not uncommon and there are a lot of inconsistencies in stamping. For the UK specifically, you can always mention your Polish/EU citizenship and show your other passport while still using the Canadian passport.

Comment: To avoid questions about overstaying in Gibraltar, keep receipts for travel to and from (air fare, ferry tickets, whatever). Also, keep receipts for purchases made outside Gibraltar for the week after you left. Having proof of hotel stays, meals, etc purchased in Spain, the UK, _anywhere_ but there should relieve concerns should anyone decide to question it. As noted in the answers so far, you shouldn't have any problems, but this is an extra level of insurance.

Comment: Just to support this answer, I have had a similar thing happen to me (UK/US national, back when the UK was in the EU). For some reason I showed a border guard in the EU my US passport. He flipped it open to a random page, smacked the stamp down without even looking at me, and waved me on. I don't even remember what country it was, or even that it had happened until I read this question. So +1 to "don't sweat it" :)

Comment: Oh wow, interesting that the same happened to you! How long ago was that?

Answer (score 13):

You are overreacting, as you guessed.
First of all, if there is any question at any time, you can show both passports and explain that you expected to get an entry stamp into the UK/Gibraltar. Neither Canada nor Poland has any problem with dual nationality.

But even more important, that stamp in your passport is just that, a stamp, it does not have a corresponding digital registration as those are not yet made in the Schengen area. This makes it very unlikely you will ever be asked about that exit stamp.

Other countries may be interested if you apply for a visa, but that should not be a problem either, as you can proof you entered the Schengen area on your Schengen area passport.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience! Hypothetical question: if someone who is not-EU (example, Canadian) flew Canada > Switzerland, and then drove through France to Spain, and then crossed Gibraltar on foot, they would also just get an exit stamp **only**, correct? Since Switzerland does not stamp and land borders don’t stamp either. So my exit stamp might not be so weird; could have come through Switzerland.

Comment: @PierogiGirl Switzerland is part of the Schengen area, you should get a stamp upon landing in Switzerland. What makes you think they don't?

Comment: @PierogiGirl I can confirm Relaxed is correct. Non-EU non-Schengen passports will be stamped by Switzerland on entry from non-Schengen countries unless you have a Schengen residence permit.

Comment: Oh….I don’t know. So I guess it’s obvious I’m a dual citizen now. Ugh, this is such a disaster.

Comment: Why is being a dual citizen such a problem? Neither country does have a problem with it and Canada will most likely not even notice that stamp.

Comment: I’m more concerned when applying for visas from a third country, using my Canadian (main) passport. 

It will be very obvious that I’m a dual citizen from my stamp history … and if visa applications ask if I am a dual citizen, I will always have to put "yes" now

Comment: @PierogiGirl Not exactly, like I said oversights are common, border guards and even consulates don't necessarily pay that much attention to it. Still not clear why you would be so concerned about it in any case. Is there any country in the world where being a Polish citizen is an issue? It's not going to last very long either, you will eventually renew your passport.

Comment: Incidentally, what does matter a lot more is where you apply for a visa. If you apply for a visa for a third country at their consulate in some EU country but your Canadian passport is pristine (no stamp, long-term visa or residence permit) then it's obvious that you have another citizenship. If you apply from Canada, you have a bunch of stamps but one is missing, it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Relaxed, ironic username as I am just a nervous wreck in general  My main concern is that whenever applying for a visa for third country (say, in Asia), they sometimes ask, “Do you possess another nationality?” I usually put “No”, as a matter of course. Never been an issue. Now I’m concerned that I will always have to put “Yes”, including to other countries I’ve visited in the past . But maybe can just chalk up that stamp to oversight, as you said. Unfortunately I just got this passport in November 2021, if it was expiring in a year or two I wouldn’t be concerned!

Comment: So you have always been lying on visa applications? Not a smart move. If found out lying you can get a ban, not just for that country but for many more. If asked for something tell the truth.

Comment: No, I only applied for and got this Polish passport (by descent) later, after I had already visited those countries when I was only Canadian.

Comment: I would suggest a whole new question, @PierogiGirl, about your concerns about what effect having dual Polish/Canadian citizenship on planned or hypothetical future travel plans. This is obviously something that concerns you as well, and it deserves a whole new topic here. Folks here won't be able to give you good, thorough answers down here in the comments, plus it's just not how [travel.se] is designed to work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion; yes, I am just a bit concerned. Do you know which forum I should post that in?

Comment: @PierogiGirl You can post it here I think but as a new question, spelling out exactly what your concern is (possibly which countries you want to visit, etc.)